# LiveData remove Observer after first callback

Tags: android, observers, android-room, android-livedata

How do I remove the observer after I receive the first result? Below are two code ways I've tried, but they both keep receiving updates even though I have removed the observer.

```
Observer observer = new Observer<DownloadItem>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable DownloadItem downloadItem) {
            if(downloadItem!= null) {
                DownloadManager.this.downloadManagerListener.onDownloadManagerFailed(null, "this item already exists");
                return;
            }
            startDownload();
            model.getDownloadByContentId(contentId).removeObservers((AppCompatActivity)context);
        }
    };
    model.getDownloadByContentId(contentId).observeForever(observer);
```

---

```
 model.getDownloadByContentId(contentId).observe((AppCompatActivity)context, downloadItem-> {
             if(downloadItem!= null) {
                this.downloadManagerListener.onDownloadManagerFailed(null, "this item already exists");
                return;
            }
            startDownload();
            model.getDownloadByContentId(contentId).removeObserver(downloadItem-> {});
        } );
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Your first one will not work, because `observeForever()` is not tied to any `LifecycleOwner`.

Your second one will not work, because you are not passing the existing registered observer to `removeObserver()`.

You first need to settle on whether you are using `LiveData` with a `LifecycleOwner` (your activity) or not. My assumption is that you should be using a `LifecycleOwner`. In that case, use:

```
Observer observer = new Observer<DownloadItem>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable DownloadItem downloadItem) {
        if(downloadItem!= null) {
            DownloadManager.this.downloadManagerListener.onDownloadManagerFailed(null, "this item already exists");
            return;
        }
        startDownload();
        model.getDownloadByContentId(contentId).removeObservers((AppCompatActivity)context);
    }
};

model.getDownloadByContentId(contentId).observe((AppCompatActivity)context, observer);
```

Comment: This will remove all Observers from the Activity/Fragment. How we can remove only the current Observer, not all?

Comment: @MrVasilev: I do not know what "current" means in this context. To remove a single observer, call `removeObserver()` on the `LiveData`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Sorry if I wasn't clear. When I try to do that:                        
var liveData = viewModel.findNearestDriver(location)
        liveData.observe(this, Observer {
            liveData.removeObserver(this)
        })                                                                                                                   I received "Type mismatch" compile error, because this is not my Observer, but my Fragment

Comment: @MrVasilev: That might be an issue with Kotlin SAM support for lambdas or something. You may need to use `object : Observer` and create a "real" `Observer` instance, in order to get the correct `this` from inside that `Observer`'s `onChanged()` function.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for you response, you are right it was an issue with Kotlin. Just mention that for Kotlin maybe the solution is to create a extension of 'LiveData' like that:                                                                       fun <T> LiveData<T>.observeOnlyOnce(lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner, observer: Observer<T>) {
    observe(lifecycleOwner, object : Observer<T> {
        override fun onChanged(t: T?) {
            observer.onChanged(t)
            removeObserver(this)
        }
    })
}

Comment: Hi All, please follow this link https://blog.mindorks.com/observe-event-only-once-using-single-live-event and implement single live event concept and dont use observeForever with this regard, use observe and it will work fine

Answer (score 120):

There is a more convenient solution for Kotlin with extensions:

```
fun <T> LiveData<T>.observeOnce(lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner, observer: Observer<T>) {
    observe(lifecycleOwner, object : Observer<T> {
        override fun onChanged(t: T?) {
            observer.onChanged(t)
            removeObserver(this)
        }
    })
}
```

This extension permit us to do that:

```
liveData.observeOnce(this, Observer<Password> {
    if (it != null) {
        // do something
    }
})
```

So to answer your original question, we can do that:

```
val livedata = model.getDownloadByContentId(contentId)
livedata.observeOnce((AppCompatActivity) context, Observer<T> {
    if (it != null) {
        DownloadManager.this.downloadManagerListener.onDownloadManagerFailed(null, "this item already exists");
    }
    startDownload();
})
```

The original source is here: https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/android/android-livedata-observe-once-only-kotlin/

Update: @Hakem-Zaied is right, we need to use `observe` instead of `observeForever`.

Comment: May I suggest to first remove the observer - only _then_ calling the users' `onChanged`. Otherwise, should the user's implementation throw an exception, the intermediate observer would remain registered "forever".

Comment: in case it's not obvious where to declare an extension function, see: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#scope-of-extensions

Comment: Awesome answer! I modified it slightly so it's even more Kotlinish now! https://gist.github.com/bartekpacia/eb1c92886acf3972c3f030cde2579ebb

Comment: This code has a problem. You need to add a check to see if the lifecycle owner is destroyed otherwise it could cause a leak and problems trying to call methods or properties of a destroyed fragment. You should edit this and add this to the onChanged: if (owner.lifecycle.currentState == Lifecycle.State.DESTROYED) { removeObserver(this) return }

Comment: @paul_f I don't think so, if the owner is already destroyed than `observe` will ignore the call. Check the source [here](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:lifecycle/lifecycle-livedata-core/src/main/java/androidx/lifecycle/LiveData.java;l=179-180;drc=4a302c8fadff7fefa27c7172d77d1128a2fa8f13)

Comment: @paul_f If the current owner is destroyed after, than the observer is automatically removed [here](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:lifecycle/lifecycle-livedata-core/src/main/java/androidx/lifecycle/LiveData.java;l=418-421;drc=4a302c8fadff7fefa27c7172d77d1128a2fa8f13)

Answer (score 44):

I love the generic solutions by [Vince](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7947225/vince) and [Hakem Zaied](https://stackoverflow.com/users/601550/hakem-zaied), but to me the lambda version seems even better:

```
fun <T> LiveData<T>.observeOnce(observer: (T) -> Unit) {
    observeForever(object: Observer<T> {
        override fun onChanged(value: T) {
            removeObserver(this)
            observer(value)
        }
    })
}

fun <T> LiveData<T>.observeOnce(owner: LifecycleOwner, observer: (T) -> Unit) {
    observe(owner, object: Observer<T> {
        override fun onChanged(value: T) {
            removeObserver(this)
            observer(value)
        }
    })
}
```

So you end up with:

```
    val livedata = model.getDownloadByContentId(contentId)
    livedata.observeOnce(context as AppCompatActivity) {
        if (it != null) {
            DownloadManager.this.downloadManagerListener.onDownloadManagerFailed(null, "this item already exists")
        }
        startDownload();
    }
```

Which I find cleaner.

Also, `removeObserver()` is called first-thing as the observer is dispatched, which makes it safer (i.e. copes with potential runtime error throws from within the user's observer code).

Comment: Perfect answer for Kotlin users!
I just wrote the same code and wanted to post it until I found this. +1

Comment: This code has a problem. You need to add a check to see if the lifecycle owner is destroyed otherwise it could cause a leak and problems trying to call methods or properties of a destroyed fragment. You should edit this and add this to the onChanged: if (owner.lifecycle.currentState == Lifecycle.State.DESTROYED) {
                removeObserver(this)
                return
            }

Comment: if i use this inside oncreateview, it triggers whenever i come back to the fragment, any suggestion in which lifecycle method should i use this?

Comment: Thanks. This ease the problem well.

Comment: There's a typo in the extension functions, observer(value) should be observer.onChanged(value)

Comment: This code cannot use observer from variable, sometimes need to reuse same observer to different livedata

Answer (score 38):

Following on [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) answer, instead of calling `removeObservers()` which will remove all the observers attached to the LiveData, you can simply call `removeObserver(this)` to only remove this observer:

```
Observer observer = new Observer<DownloadItem>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable DownloadItem downloadItem) {
        if(downloadItem!= null) {
            DownloadManager.this.downloadManagerListener.onDownloadManagerFailed(null, "this item already exists");
            return;
        }
        startDownload();
        model.getDownloadByContentId(contentId).removeObserver(this);
    }
};

model.getDownloadByContentId(contentId).observe((AppCompatActivity)context, observer);
```

**Note:** in `removeObserver(this)`, `this` refers to the observer instance and this works only in the case of an anonymous inner class. If you use a lambda, then `this` will refer to the activity instance.

Comment: Careful here...Depending on how fast your query returns, this can actually cause an infinite loop where model.myThing returns BEFORE the call to removeObserver (I had this happen to me).

Comment: @Psest328 How exactly this can cause loop?

Comment: Am I wrong in saying that `LiveData` does not seem to have a method `removeObservers()` without parameters? I can't seem to find a way to remove all observers without knowing about the lifecycleOwner.

Comment: @Nick you're calling the method and kicking it off in the process of calling remove observer.  If that process finishes BEFORE the observer is removed, it causes an infinite loop.  You're basically creating a race condition

Comment: @Psest328 "BEFORE the observer is removed" The observer is being removed  synchronously...

Comment: @Nick I know what's supposed to be happening, just relaying an issue I ran into.  Granted, the database was empty so it was super fast to query and it didn't reproduce EVERY time... but it did reproduce

Comment: I'm using Fragment, and when calling `removeObserver(this)`, it does nothing, I tried `System.out.println(this);` to debug and it prints out the Fragment not the observer

Answer (score 18):

I agree with [Vince](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7947225/vince) above, but I believe that we either skip passing `lifecycleOwner` and use `observerForever` as below:

```
fun <T> LiveData<T>.observeOnce(observer: Observer<T>) {
    observeForever(object : Observer<T> {
        override fun onChanged(t: T?) {
            observer.onChanged(t)
            removeObserver(this)
        }
    })
}
```

Or, using the `lifecycleOwner` with `observe` as below:

```
fun <T> LiveData<T>.observeOnce(lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner, observer: Observer<T>) {
    observe(lifecycleOwner, object : Observer<T> {
        override fun onChanged(t: T?) {
            observer.onChanged(t)
            removeObserver(this)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: are you able to post same answer using Java?  I have zero knowledge of Kotlin.

Comment: This code has a problem. You need to add a check to see if the lifecycle owner is destroyed otherwise it could cause a leak and problems trying to call methods or properties of a destroyed fragment. You should edit this and add this to the onChanged: if (owner.lifecycle.currentState == Lifecycle.State.DESTROYED) { removeObserver(this) return }

Comment: Thanks, it works, but unsubscribes in all cases. For instance, you load a list, having three states: loading, success, error. Then you will see only loading state. To fix it, unsubscribe after finished states (success, error).

Answer (score 10):

Java version of `observeOnce` method is already suggested by many users. But here we'll se the implementation in the main code.

First, we need to create **Util class method**

```
public class LiveDataUtil {
public static <T> void observeOnce(final LiveData<T> liveData, final Observer<T> observer) {
    liveData.observeForever(new Observer<T>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(T t) {
            liveData.removeObserver(this);
            observer.onChanged(t);
        }
    });
}}
```

Now, we need to call this class where we need our ViewModel.

```
LiveDataUtil.observeOnce(viewModel.getUserDetails(), response-> {
    if(response.isSuccessful()){
       //Do your task
    }
}
```

That's All!

Answer (score 8):

Here's a Java version of the `observeOnce` method suggested in the other answers (an util class method instead of a Kotlin extension function) :

```
public class LiveDataUtil {

    public static <T> void observeOnce(final LiveData<T> liveData, final Observer<T> observer) {
        liveData.observeForever(new Observer<T>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(T t) {
                liveData.removeObserver(this);
                observer.onChanged(t);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

You are creating live data instance (model.getDownloadByContentId(contentId)) more than one time that is the problem here.

Try this:

```
LiveData myLiveData =model.getDownloadByContentId(contentId);
myLiveData.observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), downloadItem-> {
         if(downloadItem!= null) {
            this.downloadManagerListener.onDownloadManagerFailed(null, "this item already exists");
            return;
        }
        startDownload();
       myLiveData.removeObservers(getViewLifecycleOwner());
    } );
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution proposed by @CommonsWare and @Toni Joe didn't solve the issue for me when I needed to remove the observers after receiving the first result from a DAO query in my ViewModel. However, the following solution found at [Livedata keeps observer after calling removeObserer](http://arushipant.pratibimb.co/post/bug-fix-livedata-keeps-observing-even-after-calling-removeobserver-18/) did the trick for me with a little of my own intuition.

The process is as follows, create a variable in your ViewModel where the LiveData is stored upon request, retrieve it in a create observer function call in the activity after doing a null check, and call a remove observers function before calling the flushToDB routine in an imported class. That is, the code in my ViewModel looks as follows:

```
public class GameDataModel extends AndroidViewModel {
   private LiveData<Integer> lastMatchNum = null;
   .
   .
   .
   private void initLastMatchNum(Integer player1ID, Integer player2ID) {
       List<Integer> playerIDs = new ArrayList<>();
       playerIDs.add(player1ID);
       playerIDs.add(player2ID);

       lastMatchNum = mRepository.getLastMatchNum(playerIDs);
   }

 public LiveData<Integer> getLastMatchNum(Integer player1ID, Integer player2ID) {
       if (lastMatchNum == null) { initLastMatchNum(player1ID, player2ID); }
       return lastMatchNum;
   }
```

In the above, if there is no data in the LiveData variable in the ViewModel, I call `initLastMatchNum()` to retrieve the data from a function within the view model. The function to be called from the activity is `getLastMatchNum()`. This routine retrieves the data in the variable in the ViewModel (which is retrieved via the repository via the DAO).

The following code I have in my Activity

```
public class SomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         .
         .
         .
        setupLastMatchNumObserver(); 
         .
         .
         .
    }

    private void setupLastMatchNumObserver() {
        if (mGameDataViewModel.getLastMatchNum(Player1ID, Player2ID).hasObservers()) {
            Log.v("Observers", "setupLastMatchNumObserver has observers...returning");
            return;
        }
        Log.v("Setting up Observers", "running mGameDataViewModel.get...observer()");
        mGameDataViewModel.getLastMatchNum(Player1ID, Player2ID).observe(this, new Observer<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Integer MatchNumber) {
                if (MatchNumber == null ) {
                    matchNumber = 1;
                    Log.v( "null MatchNumber", "matchNumber: " + matchNumber.toString());
                }
                else {
                    matchNumber = MatchNumber; matchNumber++;
                    Log.v( "matchNumber", "Incrementing match number: " + matchNumber.toString());
                }
                MatchNumberText.setText(matchNumber.toString());
            }
        });
    }

    private void removeObservers() {
        final LiveData<Integer> observable = mGameDataViewModel.getLastMatchNum(Player1ID, Player2ID);
        if (observable != null && observable.hasObservers()) {
            Log.v("removeObserver", "Removing Observers");
            observable.removeObservers(this);
        }
    }
```

What's going on in the above, is 1.) I call the `setupLastMatchNumObserver()` routine in the `onCreate` method of the activity, to update the class's variable `matchNum`. This keeps track of the match numbers between players in my game which is stored in a database. Every set of players will have a different match number in the database based upon how often they play new matches with each other. The first solutions in this thread seemed a little weary to me as calling remove observers in the `onChanged` seems strange to me and would constantly change the `TextView` object after every database flush of each move of the players. So `matchNumber` was getting incremented after every move because there was a new value in the database after the first move (namely the one `matchNumber++` value) and `onChanged` kept being called because `removeObservers` was not working as intended. `setupLastMatchNumObserver()` checks to see if there are observers of the live data and if so does not instantiate a new call each round. As you can see I am setting a `TextView` object to reflect the current matchnumber of the players.

The next part is a little trick on when to call `removeObservers()`. At first I thought if I called it directly after `setupLastMatchNumObserver()` in the `onCreate` override of the activity that all would be fine. But it removed the observer before the observer could grab the data. I found out that if I called `removeObservers()` directly prior to the call to flush the new data collected in the activity to the database  (in separate routines throughout the activity) it worked like a charm. i.e.,

```
 public void addListenerOnButton() {
        .
        .
        .
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               .
               .
               .
               removeObservers();
               updateMatchData(data); 
            }
   }
```

I also call `removeObservers();` and `updateMatchData(data)` in other places in my activity in the above fashion. The beauty is `removeObservers()` can be called as many times as needed since there is a check to return if there are no observers present.

Answer (score 1):

1. LiveData class has 2 similar methods to remove Observers. First is named,

`removeObserver(@NonNull final Observer<T> observer)` (see carefully the name of the method, it's singular) which takes in the observer you want to be removed from the list of Observers of the same LifecycleOwner.

2. Second method is

`removeObservers(@NonNull final LifecycleOwner owner)` (see the plural method name). This method takes in the LifecycleOwner itself and removes all the Observers of the specified LifecycleOwner.

Now in your case, you can remove your Observer by 2 ways (there might be many ways), one is told by @ToniJoe in the previous answer.

Another way is just have a MutableLiveData of boolean in your ViewModel which stores true when it's been Observed the first time and just observe that Livedata as well. So whenever it turns to true, you'll be notified and there you can remove your observer by passing that particular observer.

Answer (score 1):

Vince and Hakem Zaied solutions worked well, but in my case, I was trying to get the livedata instance and update a local DB, but the livedata was to be updated from a remote API first, hence I was getting a NullPointer, so I switched to observeForever and I was able to get the data when it was updated, but now I had to dispose of the observer after getting the data, so I modified Vince solution to only observe and emit data when the livedata contained data.

```
   fun <T> LiveData<T>.observeOnce(observer: (T) -> Unit) {
    observeForever(object : Observer<T> {
        override fun onChanged(value: T) {

            //Resource is my data class response wrapper, with this i was able to 
            //only update the observer when the livedata had values
            //the idea is to cast the value to the expected type and check for nulls

            val resource = value as Resource<*>
            if (resource.data != null) {
                observer(value)
                removeObserver(this)
            }}
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a  androidx.lifecycle.Observer Java example:

```
Observer <? super List<MyEntity>> observer = new Observer<List<MyEntity>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(List<MyEntity> myEntities) {
        Log.d(TAG, "observer changed");

       MySearchViewModel.getMyList().removeObserver(this);
    }
};
MySearchViewModel.getMyList().observe(MainActivity.this, observer);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, Livedata is designed to continually receive oncoming data. If you just want it to be executed only once for the purpose of, say, requesting data from server to initialize UI, I would recommend you design your code in this way:

1、Define your time-consuming method as **non-Livedata** type inside a Viewmodel. You do not have to start a new thread in this process.

2、Start a **new Thread** in an Activity, and inside the new Thread, call the method defined above, followed by `runOnUiThread()` where you write your logic of utilizing the requested data. In thie way the time-consuming method will not block the UI thread, while it blocks the new thread so the runOnUiThread() only runs after your requested data is received successfully.

So consider a replacement of Livedata, if this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I read some documentation and saw at the observer the remove method and so I came to this solution:

**1: first declare the observer:**

```
// observer for selecting chip in view
View actionView;
Observer selectChipFunction = (action) -> selectChip(actionView, action);
```

**2: then use the observer:**

```
// select an action if set before
if (sharedViewModel.getAction() != null)
    sharedViewModel.getAction().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), selectChipFunction);
```

**3: then in the selectChip observer remove the observer:**

```
/**
 * select action chip
 * @param actionView - view to use for selecting action chip
 * @param actionObject - action chip to select
 */
private void selectChip(View actionView, Object actionObject)
{
    // no need for observing when action is changed so remove.
    sharedViewModel.getAction().removeObserver(selectChipFunction);
```

This way its only triggered once and after that its removed. In my case I needed this because I was setting the "action" that triggered the Observer in the selectChipFunction and if I dont do this you will end in a cyclic observer triggering.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
fun <T> LiveData<T>.observeOnCondition(lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner,
                                       observer: Observer<T>,
                                       condition: () -> Boolean) {
    observe(lifecycleOwner) { t ->
        if (condition()) {
            observer.onChanged(t)
        }
    }
}
```

This way you can define a more generic condition if you might want to pick up the data again at a later stage.

Answer (score 0):

*you can use such function to observe once then remove the observer*

```
fun <T> LiveData<T>.observeOnce(lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner, observer: Observer<T>) {
    var ob: Observer<T>? = null

    ob = Observer { value ->
        ob?.let {
            removeObserver(it)
        }
        observer.onChanged(value)
    }

    observe(lifecycleOwner, ob)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, all solution didn't work for me. The only example that worked for me see that link.

https://gist.github.com/kobeumut/edb3edd9a2ae9abf6984a42bb2de0441