# How can I get SAM Interface's object in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Suppose I am Observing a LiveData in a Fragment and I want to remove observer after  I received the data.

eg:

```
val testLiveData = MutableLiveData<String>()
```

and Observing as:

```
testLiveData.observe(this, Observer<String> {
        //TODO://Remove this Observer from here
        //testLiveData.removeObserver(this)
    })
```

How can I do that? Calling "this" is giving me an instance of the Fragment instead of the current Observer.

However, I can do like this.

```
 testLiveData.observe(this, object : Observer<String>{
        override fun onChanged(t: String?) {
            testLiveData.removeObserver(this)
        }

    })
```

Is there any way to do the same in SAM?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47872807/3544839

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you cannot access `this` since it is not guaranteed that every invocation of `observe` creates a new instance of `Observer<String>`.
If the lambda does not access any variable within the function where it is defined, the corresponding anonymous class instance is reused between calls (i.e., a singleton `Observer` is created that is used for every `observe` call).

Thus, for implementing listeners, the second variant (`object : Observer<String>`) should be used. This enforces that a new `Observer` is created every time `observe` is called, which in turn can then be accessed as `this` within its implemented methods.