# ManyToMany POJOS in RoomDB: how can I obtain related objects's list sorted by junction sorting number?

Tags: java, android, sql, many-to-many, android-room

In the same code that I used in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69907356/3692177), I would like to obtain the "composite ManyToMany POJO"s with it's "related objects list" sorted by a number column in the junction table.

### My DAO's SQL STATEMENT

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM teacher " +
        "INNER JOIN teacherscourses AS tc ON teacher.t_id = tc.teacher_id " +
        "INNER JOIN course AS c ON c.c_id = tc.course_id " +
        "WHERE tc.course_id = :course_id " +
        "ORDER BY teacher.t_id ASC, tc.course_order ASC"
)
public abstract List<TeacherWithCourses> getTeachersByCourseId(short course_id);
```

The generated DAO's method obtains the list of TeacherWithCourses objects as expected. These objects' `courses` list property gets the related objects as expected; but the "ORDER BY" clause doesn't seem to affect how these `courses` list is sorted at all.

I expected each internal list in these objects (`List<Course> courses`) to be sorted according to the junction table's `tc.course_order` number; but the obtained objects seem to come sorted arbitrarily.

### The "composite" POJO

```
public class TeacherWithCourses implements Serializable {
    @Embedded public Teacher teacher;
    @Relation(
            parentColumn = "t_id",
            entity = Course.class,
            entityColumn = "c_id",
            associateBy = @Junction(
                    value = TeachersCourses.class,
                    parentColumn = "teacher_id",
                    entityColumn = "course_id"
            )
    )
    public List<Course> courses;
}
```

---

Is this kind of sorting possible through SQL query, or must I implement it some other way?

## [EDIT] The Junction Entity

I store the ordering criteria inside an extra column here:

```
@Entity(primaryKeys = {"teacher_id", "course_id"})
public class TeachersCourses implements Serializable {

    @ColumnInfo(name = "teacher_id")
    public int teacherId;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "course_id")
    public short courseId;
    @ColumnInfo(index = true, name = "course_order")
    public short courseOrder;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> but the obtained objects seem to come sorted arbitrarily.

This is because of how @Relation works. It does not include/consider the child objects from the query, it uses the query just to extract and build the parent. It then gets, irrespective of the supplied query, ALL of the children for the parent via a query that is build according to the attributes of the @Relation.

As such to filter and or order the children you need to supplement @Relation by overwriting the list/array of children.

For convenience based upon my previous answer *(so using `AltCourse` with changed column names)* here's an example of one way that is easy to implement (but not the most efficient).

First the additional @Dao components :-

```
@Query("SELECT altcourse.* FROM altcourse " +
        "JOIN teacherscourses ON teacherscourses.course_id = altcourse.courseid " +
        "JOIN teacher ON teacher.id = teacherscourses.teacher_id " +
        "WHERE teacher.id=:id ORDER BY teacherscourses.course_order ASC")
public abstract List<AltCourse> getSortedCoursesForATeacher(int id);


@Transaction
public List<AltTeacherWithCourses> getAltTeachersByCourseIdSorted(short course_id) {
    List<AltTeacherWithCourses> rv = getAltTeachersByCourseId(course_id);
    for (AltTeacherWithCourses twc: rv) {
        twc.courses = getSortedCoursesForATeacher(twc.teacher.id);
    }
    return rv;
}
```

- *obviously change anything starting with Alt accordingly*

So a query that extracts the courses in the correct order, and

A method that gets the original `teachersWithCourses` where the Courses are not sorted as expected and replaces the list of courses with the sorted courses as extracted by the additional query.

**Alt** version have been used in the above for testing so with the tables looking like :-

[image]

and

[image]

Running :-

```
    for(Course c: dao.getAllCourses()) {
        for (AltTeacherWithCourses tbc: dao.getAltTeachersByCourseIdSorted(c.id)) {
            Log.d("TEACHER_SORTC","Teacher is " + tbc.teacher.name + " Courses = " + tbc.courses.size());
            for(AltCourse course: tbc.courses) {
                Log.d("COURSE_SORTC","\tCourse is " + course.coursename);
            }
        }
    }
```

Results in :-

```
2021-11-11 15:26:01.559 D/TEACHER_SORTC: Teacher is Teacher1 Courses = 3
2021-11-11 15:26:01.559 D/COURSE_SORTC:     Course is AltCourse3
2021-11-11 15:26:01.559 D/COURSE_SORTC:     Course is AltCourse2
2021-11-11 15:26:01.559 D/COURSE_SORTC:     Course is AltCourse1
2021-11-11 15:26:01.565 D/TEACHER_SORTC: Teacher is Teacher1 Courses = 3
2021-11-11 15:26:01.565 D/COURSE_SORTC:     Course is AltCourse3
2021-11-11 15:26:01.565 D/COURSE_SORTC:     Course is AltCourse2
2021-11-11 15:26:01.565 D/COURSE_SORTC:     Course is AltCourse1
2021-11-11 15:26:01.568 D/TEACHER_SORTC: Teacher is Teacher1 Courses = 3
2021-11-11 15:26:01.568 D/COURSE_SORTC:     Course is AltCourse3
2021-11-11 15:26:01.569 D/COURSE_SORTC:     Course is AltCourse2
2021-11-11 15:26:01.569 D/COURSE_SORTC:     Course is AltCourse1
2021-11-11 15:26:01.569 D/TEACHER_SORTC: Teacher is Teacher2 Courses = 1
2021-11-11 15:26:01.569 D/COURSE_SORTC:     Course is AltCourse3
```

**Additional**

An alternative/more efficient (SQLite wise) approach is to use a more complex query along with a POJO that uses @Embedded for Teacher and Course.

Thus you extract objects that have a Teacher and a Course and then you can build the TeachersWithCourses from the extract.

This does not need additional queries as are run when using @Relation and thus there is no need for an @Transaction.

- note the example is using the original Teacher and Course without unique names so would have to be modified accordingly.

First the TeacherCourse POJO :-

```
class TeacherCourse {
    @Embedded
    Teacher teacher;
    @Embedded(prefix = "course")
    Course course;
}
```

- prefix used to circumvent duplicate column names.

The query :-

```
@Query("WITH teacher_in_course AS (" +
        "SELECT teacher.id " +
        "FROM teacher " +
        "JOIN teacherscourses ON teacher.id = teacherscourses.teacher_id " +
        "WHERE course_id = :courseId" +
        ")" +
        "SELECT course.id AS courseid, course.name as coursename, teacher.* " +
        "FROM course " +
        "JOIN teacherscourses ON course.id = teacherscourses.course_id " +
        "JOIN teacher ON teacher.id = teacherscourses.teacher_id " +
        "WHERE teacher.id IN (SELECT * FROM teacher_in_course) " +
        "ORDER BY teacher.id ASC, course_order ASC" +
        ";")
public abstract  List<TeacherCourse> getTeachersCoursesSortedFromCourseId(short courseId);
```

- the CTE (Common Table Expression) `teacher_in_course` retrieves the list of teachers who have the specified courseid. This is used in the actual query to get the teachers and ALL courses for each of the teachers ordered accordingly. As such there is no need for @Transaction as all the data is extracted in the single query.

However, a TeachersWithCourses list needs to be built from the list of TeacherCourse objects e.g. :-

```
public List<TeacherWithCourses> buildTeacherWithCoursesListFromTeacherCourseList(List<TeacherCourse> teacherCourseList) {

    ArrayList<TeacherWithCourses> rv = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean afterFirst = false;
    TeacherWithCourses currentTWC = new TeacherWithCourses();
    currentTWC.teacher = new Teacher(-1,"");
    ArrayList<Course> currentCourseList = new ArrayList<>();
    currentTWC.courses = currentCourseList;
    for (TeacherCourse tc: teacherCourseList) {
        if(currentTWC.teacher.id != tc.teacher.id) {
            if (afterFirst) {
                currentTWC.courses = currentCourseList;
                rv.add(currentTWC);
                currentCourseList = new ArrayList<>();
                currentTWC = new TeacherWithCourses();
            }
            currentTWC.teacher = tc.teacher;
            currentTWC.courses = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        currentCourseList.add(tc.course);
        afterFirst = true;
    }
    if (afterFirst) {
        currentTWC.courses = currentCourseList;
        rv.add(currentTWC);
    }
    return rv;
}
```

Comment: I am almost there: once I figure out howto make `getAltTeachersByCourseIdSorted` return the list as `LiveData<>`, I shall be able to see if this implementations does what I need (although seeing your examples it makes sense)

Comment: I figured it out already. I changed your `return rv;` into `return new MutableLiveData<>(rv);`. It crashes with `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.`. The lifehack of using `AsyncTask`s to workaround this issue worked for `INSERT`-like statements, but for `SELECT` it would probably be madness... am I crazy? Well... maybe... xD

Comment: @SebasSBM As I have never used, and possibly never will use, LiveData etc so I can't really help. I limit my help to the SQLite aspect of Room; queries/relationships/schemas and so on. As such I always use `.allowMainThreadQueries` when writing code  for answers.

Comment: In any case, your help is appreciated. I noticed your solution at least worked for you, so you have my +1. However, I still struggle using RoomDB because I feel that anything I need to show in UI based on some DB data, either I use `LiveData<>` or it is never shown at all; beside, I try to avoid using `.allowMainThreadQueries` on purpose so the `IllegalStateExceptions` will force me to search a more optimal approach...

Comment: I the end, I delegated `getAltTeachersByCourseIdSorted` not to the DAO, but to the ViewModel instead. Exactly the same code than the mentioned function, but run into an `AsyncTask`. Then, in `OnPostExecute` method for the AsyncTask, I use the output to feed `setValue` on a `MutableLiveData` that is holded by the ViewModel. This way, `Observer`s that observe the LiveData for the `TeacherWithCourses` list with sorted courses are aware of the change once AsyncTask is done loading the sorting list. Maybe later I post it as an answer...

Answer (score 0):

From what it looks like you have two options.
Here is an article explaining both methods https://newbedev.com/using-room-s-relation-with-order-by

You can sort your `List` after its been pulled from the database.
Using `Collections.Sort`. This will remove a lot of complexity from your query. And is probably the best option.

or

You can split your query into 3 parts and manually create a `List` of `TeacherWithCourses`, a query pulls a `List` of `Teacher` and then uses each teacher to pull their `Courses` in the order you desire. This is more queries but can be down under a single `@Transaction` so there will be little felt repercussions on the database side. But be careful this can create a lot of objects fast.

Comment: `Collections.Sort` would be a good solution, but I am confused about it's implementation because of the sorting number is actually on the junction table (each TeacherID-CourseID composite key has his own `course_order` column), which I actually want to affect how Courses are sorted. I tried implementing `Comparable` to the junction entity's table, but that won't let me finish the job because the elements of the list aren't actually `Comparable`. So, should I make some "wrapper POJO" for "Courses" entity in order to make it `Comparable` the way I intended?

Comment: ...I think I got delusional. Perhaps my only option is splitting the query into 3 parts...

Comment: Here is something that may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63887061/android-room-many-to-many-junction-table-getting-more-than-relation-of-2-tables, avoid using Junction and just stick courseOrder in your composite pojo and pull it when you do the query for the pojo.