# Get initial data from ViewModel once Fragemnt appears

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mvvm

I am new to Android and its ViewModel patters. What I would like to achive is everytime user enter into Fragment then data is being fetched from server.

So basically what I have right now is:

ViewModel

```
class HomeViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val data = MutableLiveData<DataModel>()

    init {
        initialize()
    }

    private suspend fun initialize() {
        //HTTP REQUEST...
        data.value = apiresult
    }
}
```

Fragment

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
private lateinit var viewModel: HomeViewModel

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[HomeViewModel::class.java]

    viewModel.data.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        //Do some stuff on UI
    }

}
```

I was reading Android ViewModel lifecycle docs and currently it is as expected. The init function block is being called once. This leads whenever user enter once again to the fragment then initialize() function won't be called. The initial data value from ViewModel notifies HomeFragment whenever after will be launched.

I tried to do it simple as possible so in HomeFragment`s onCreateView() method to call:

viewModel.initialize()

Above solution works but observer callback is called twice: first with previous value and second time with new API data.

Is there an option to register LiveData just once or I should unsubsrive from LiveData in any of Android overridable methods like onDestroy()?

Comment: So you want the ViewModel to fetch the data every time the Fragment is visible to the user?

Comment: Exacly, everytime user enter fragment I would like to get new data

Comment: `val data = liveData { emit(getApiResult()) }` https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#livedata

Comment: in not being executed when i enter the fragment after first time

Comment: In this case, you should create a function on ViewModel called "onScreenAppeared" and call it on the fragment onStart method.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an option to register LiveData just once?

Yes, you can do that using something an implementing a "observeOnce" function. Like this example: [LiveData remove Observer after first callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47854598/livedata-remove-observer-after-first-callback)

But I do not recommend this approach to solve your problem.

> or I should unsubsrive from LiveData in any of Android overridable methods like onDestroy()?

You're almost there! You should create a function on ViewModel called "onScreenAppeared" and call it on the fragment onStart method.

ViewModel:

```
class HomeViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val data = MutableLiveData<DataModel>()

    fun onScreenAppeared() {
        updateData()
    }

    private suspend fun updateData() {
        //HTTP REQUEST...
        data.value = apiresult
    }
}
```

Fragment:

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
private lateinit var viewModel: HomeViewModel

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[HomeViewModel::class.java]

    viewModel.data.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        //Do some stuff on UI
    }

}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    viewModel.onScreenAppeared()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly**, you should observe the LiveData in `onViewCreated` instead of `onCreateView` to make sure the view is fully created and ready for UI update.

**Secondly**, if you don't want to show old data of the LiveData, there are 2 options:

1/ Return a LiveData in your ViewModel's method without suspend, and observe the returned LiveData only:

```
private fun updateData(): LiveData<DataModel> {
    val result = MutableLiveData<DataModel>()
    viewModelScope.launch {
        //HTTP REQUEST...
        result.postValue(apiResult)
    }
    return result
}
```

2/ Expose a `Flow` and collect from it, the flow will be trigger each time a method is called and no old data is stored.

```
private fun updateData() = flow<DataModel> {
    //HTTP REQUEST...
    emit(apiResult)
}
```

Collect data from a `Flow` in View requires additional techniques to respect the View's Lifecycle:

```
viewModel.updateData().flowWithLifecycle(lifecycle, Lifecycle.State.STARTED).collect { 
    // Handle result
}
```