# Observe live data returned from a function

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-livedata, android-mvvm

If I return a request by `liveData` in a function and observe it in an activity to show the response, will my activity always observe `liveData` or only when the function is called?

viewModel:

```
fun blockContacts(contactList: List<Contact>): LiveData<Resource<Any>> {
    val live = MutableLiveData<Resource<Any>>(Resource.loading())
    viewModelScope.launch(ioDispatcher) {
        mutex.withLock {
        ...
        }
    }
    return live
}
```

Activity:

```
 viewModel.blockContacts(checkedList).observe(this) { res ->
             ...
         }
```

Comment: What's happening in `withLock` and, also, why would you do this?

Comment: In the `withLock`, an HTTP request is sent to the server and the value of `livedata` is set with its response. I did this to lock the Thread, it is needed due to the structure of the program.

Comment: Sorry, when asking why would you do _this_ - _this_ refers to your question. Why would you create a brand new live data object and return it instead of making it a property of the view model, which is the standard practice?

Comment: Because I only display the value of `LiveData` when making a request and I don't want to observe it all the time so that the number of activity observers does not increase.

Comment: The number of activity observes should not increase. Presumably you have one ViewModel for one Activity, which will stop observing the LiveData when it is destroyed.

Comment: Yes, it is true, but I mean the number of observers in the same activity life cycle. I have more than 50 requests like this, I don't want my activity to observe 50 liveData during its life cycle, it affects the performance.

Comment: You shouldn't have "50 requests like this" - you should observe the LiveData object _once_ and, separately, you can make 50 request that update the _one_ live data.

Comment: So you mean that my method causes liveData to be observed throughout the activity lifecycle, not just when the function is called?

Comment: Correct - calling `observe` adds the lifecycle owner (i.e., activity) the the livedata's list of observers, which will exist until you explicitly remove it, or it removes itself when it is destroyed. Your current code is potentially more wasteful as you might be creating 50 live data objects all being observed by the activity even after the function returns.

Comment: I found a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54648758/7687223