# Why LiveData observer is being triggered twice for a newly attached observer

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

*My understanding on `LiveData` is that, it will trigger observer on the current state change of data, and not a series of history state change of data.*

Currently, I have a `MainFragment`, which perform `Room` write operation, to change **non-trashed data**, to **trashed data**.

I also another `TrashFragment`, which observes to **trashed data**.

Consider the following scenario.

1. There are currently 0 **trashed data**.
2. `MainFragment` is the current active fragment. `TrashFragment` is not created yet.
3. `MainFragment` added 1 **trashed data**.
4. Now, there are 1 **trashed data**
5. We use navigation drawer, to replace `MainFragment` with `TrashFragment`.
6. `TrashFragment`'s observer will first receive `onChanged`, with 0 **trashed data**
7. Again, `TrashFragment`'s observer will secondly receive `onChanged`, with 1 **trashed data**

What is out of my expectation is that, item (6) shouldn't happen. `TrashFragment` should only receive latest **trashed data**, which is 1.

Here's my code:

### TrashFragment.java

```
public class TrashFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        noteViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(NoteViewModel.class);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...

        noteViewModel.getTrashedNotesLiveData().removeObservers(this);
        noteViewModel.getTrashedNotesLiveData().observe(this, notesObserver);
```

### MainFragment.java

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        noteViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(NoteViewModel.class);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...

        noteViewModel.getNotesLiveData().removeObservers(this);
        noteViewModel.getNotesLiveData().observe(this, notesObserver);
```

### NoteViewModel .java

```
public class NoteViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private final LiveData<List<Note>> notesLiveData;
    private final LiveData<List<Note>> trashedNotesLiveData;

    public LiveData<List<Note>> getNotesLiveData() {
        return notesLiveData;
    }

    public LiveData<List<Note>> getTrashedNotesLiveData() {
        return trashedNotesLiveData;
    }

    public NoteViewModel() {
        notesLiveData = NoteplusRoomDatabase.instance().noteDao().getNotes();
        trashedNotesLiveData = NoteplusRoomDatabase.instance().noteDao().getTrashedNotes();
    }
}
```

---

### Code which deals with Room

```
public enum NoteRepository {
    INSTANCE;

    public LiveData<List<Note>> getTrashedNotes() {
        NoteDao noteDao = NoteplusRoomDatabase.instance().noteDao();
        return noteDao.getTrashedNotes();
    }
    
    public LiveData<List<Note>> getNotes() {
        NoteDao noteDao = NoteplusRoomDatabase.instance().noteDao();
        return noteDao.getNotes();
    }
}
    
@Dao
public abstract class NoteDao {
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM note where trashed = 0")
    public abstract LiveData<List<Note>> getNotes();

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM note where trashed = 1")
    public abstract LiveData<List<Note>> getTrashedNotes();

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    public abstract long insert(Note note);
}
    
@Database(
        entities = {Note.class},
        version = 1
)
public abstract class NoteplusRoomDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    private volatile static NoteplusRoomDatabase INSTANCE;

    private static final String NAME = "noteplus";

    public abstract NoteDao noteDao();

    public static NoteplusRoomDatabase instance() {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized (NoteplusRoomDatabase.class) {
                if (INSTANCE == null) {
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(
                            NoteplusApplication.instance(),
                            NoteplusRoomDatabase.class,
                            NAME
                    ).build();
                }
            }
        }

        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Any idea how I can prevent from receiving `onChanged` twice, for a same data?

---

### Demo

I created a demo project to demonstrate this problem.

As you can see, after I perform write operation (Click on **ADD TRASHED NOTE** button) in `MainFragment`, when I switch to `TrashFragment`, I expect `onChanged` in `TrashFragment` will only be called once. However, it is being called twice.

[image]

Demo project can be downloaded from https://github.com/yccheok/live-data-problem

Comment: `LiveData` delivers whatever the last value was immediately (if a value had been posted previously), plus future changes. What is the implementation of `getTrashedNotesLiveData()`? Are you returning the `LiveData` from Room? Are you using RxJava and `LiveDataReactiveStreams`? Is this a custom `LiveData` implementation? Something else?

Comment: Just a straightforward LiveData from Room. I had updated my question to provide more info. Because before we switch to `TrashFragment`, the database supposed written with 11 trashed data. I'm not sure why the observer in TrashFragment, will first receive 10 trashed data (old snapshot), followed by 11 trashed data (latest snapshot)

Comment: We can "prevent" this from happen, by modifying our `ViewModel` to https://gist.github.com/yccheok/4bb6539c93fa39cf7dc7f08f0752d232 . Whenever before switching between `TrashFragment` and `MainFragment`, we will call `init` in `ViewModel`. However, we don't wish to go to that route yet, till we understand the problem.

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare , I had created a demo project to demonstrate the problem. Not sure you are willing to point out, which part of the code went wrong? Thank you.

Comment: You might file an issue with this sample app as evidence of a possible problem. I would get rid of the `removeObservers()` calls, as they should not be necessary in the real world and definitely are not necessary to reproduce the problem. IOW, cut the demo back to the barest minimum to illustrate the issue. It feels like you are getting a cached value initially, with the real value second, though I do not know why.

Comment: @CommonsWare check my answer and you'll know :D

Comment: Refer to this Stackoverflow post [Android Arch Components ViewModel and LiveData trigger after screen rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51450215/android-arch-components-viewmodel-and-livedate-trigger-after-screen-rotation) for a concise answer. Re: *LiveData is not designed for single events. For that reason there is a couple of ways to fix it or handle it.* (See post for solution).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I forked your project and tested it a bit. From all I can tell you discovered a serious bug.

To make the reproduction and the investigation easier, I edited your project a bit. You can find updated project here: https://github.com/techyourchance/live-data-problem . I also opened a pull request back to your repo.

To make sure that this doesn't go unnoticed, I also [opened an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79957161) in Google's issue tracker:

> Steps to reproduce:
>
> 1. Ensure that REPRODUCE_BUG is set to true in MainFragment
> 2. Install the app
> 3. Click on "add trashed note" button
> 4. Switch to TrashFragment
> 5. Note that there was just one notification form LiveData with correct value
> 6. Switch to MainFragment
> 7. Click on "add trashed note" button
> 8. Switch to TrashFragment
> 9. Note that there were two notifications from LiveData, the first one with incorrect value
>
> Note that if you set REPRODUCE_BUG  to false then the bug doesn't
>   reproduce. It demonstrates that subscription to LiveData in
>   MainFragment changed the behavior in TrashFragment.
>
> Expected result: Just one notification with correct value in any case.
>   No change in behavior due to previous subscriptions.
>
> More info: I looked at the sources a bit, and it looks like
>   notifications being triggered due to both LiveData activation and new
>   Observer subscription. Might be related to the way ComputableLiveData
>   offloads onActive() computation to Executor.

Comment: Thanks. Your modification makes the bug more apparent. Note on step 7, if we change `Click on "add trashed note" button` to `Click on "add trashed note" button 1 or multiple times`, it will become even more obvious.

Comment: Just saw your comment on the ticket. I reviewed only the open issues before submitting another ticket because it never occurred to me that something as serious as this can be dismissed so easily. You did a great job and your project clearly demonstrated the issue. I don't know why they didn't even bother to check.

Comment: A year on, and I see that this problem still exists using Oreo.

Answer (score 82):

I have introduced just one change in your code:

```
noteViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(NoteViewModel.class);
```

instead of:

```
noteViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(NoteViewModel.class);
```

in `Fragment`'s `onCreate(Bundle)` methods. And now it works seamlessly.

In your version you obtained a reference of `NoteViewModel` common to both Fragments (from Activity). `ViewModel` had `Observer` registered in previous Fragment, I think. Therefore `LiveData` kept reference to both `Observer`'s (in `MainFragment` and `TrashFragment`) and called both values.

So I guess the conclusion might be, that you should obtain `ViewModel` from `ViewModelProviders` from:

- `Fragment` in `Fragment`
- `Activity` in `Activity`

Btw.

`noteViewModel.getTrashedNotesLiveData().removeObservers(this);`

is not necessary in Fragments, however I would advise putting it in `onStop`.

Comment: But if you look at official tutorial, https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing they recommend using activity for `ViewModelProviders.of`, and fragment for `observe`.

Comment: Android official documentation presents ideal cases and is sometimes just wrong. I am not saying this is a bug or not, but helped preventing the case.

Comment: The proposed solution is wrong, as long as you will receive undesired `onChanged()` events. Assume you have already been inside `TrashFragment` once and now you have navigated to `HomeFragment`. As soon as you initiate another db change, then the subscription inside `TrashFragment` will be invoked, because you have provided a wrong `LifecycleOwner` (activity is still alive, whereas fragment is not), thus you are violating overall purpose of the `LiveData` - get the data whenever screen is actually active.

Comment: The documentation Cheok Yan Cheng points to, in fact suggests the option to share view models between fragments . But the purpose is different. As I point out in my answer, I think the two step loading is not a bug to work around but a feature to address issues like slow DB connections and rotation.

Answer (score 21):

The reason is that in your **.observe()** method, you passed a fragment as the lifecycle owner. What should have been passed is the `viewLifecycleOwner` object of the fragment

```
viewModel.livedata.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        // Do your routine here
    })
```

Comment: That was my issue. I was observing view again when I was returning to the previous fragment, that was not destroyed. 
Also valid solution would be to removeObserver in onViewDestory

Comment: @murt viewLifecycleOwner makes the Observer/LiveData aware of lifecycle, so the Observer will be unregistered automatically this avoiding the need to unregister manually in onDestroyView method

Comment: Fixed my issue after doing `flowWithLifecycle(viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle)` and `.launchIn(viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope)` in flow in fragment. Without `viewLifecycleOwner` it was observing increasingly as I went back and forth.

Answer (score 19):

## It's not a bug, it's a feature. Read why!

The observers method `void onChanged(@Nullable T t)` is called twice. That's fine.

The first time it is called upon startup. The second time it is called as soon as Room has loaded the data. Hence, upon the first call the `LiveData` object is still empty. It is designed this way for good reasons.

### Second call

Let's start with the second call, your point 7. The documentation of `Room` says:

> Room generates all the necessary code to update the LiveData object
>   when a database is updated. The generated code runs the query
>   asynchronously on a background thread when needed.

The generated code is an object of the class `ComputableLiveData` mentioned in other postings. It manages a `MutableLiveData` object. Upon this `LiveData` object it calls `LiveData::postValue(T value)` which then calls `LiveData::setValue(T value)`.

`LiveData::setValue(T value)` calls `LiveData::dispatchingValue(@Nullable ObserverWrapper initiator)`. This calls `LiveData::considerNotify(ObserverWrapper observer)` with the observer wrapper as parameter. This finally calls `onChanged()` upon the observer with the loaded data as parameter.

### First call

Now for the first call, your point 6.

You set your observers within the `onCreateView()` hook method. After this point the lifecycle changes it state twice to come visible, `on start` and `on resume`. The internal class `LiveData::LifecycleBoundObserver` is notified upon such changes of state because it implements the `GenericLifecycleObserver` interface, which holds one method named `void onStateChanged(LifecycleOwner source, Lifecycle.Event event);`.

This method calls `ObserverWrapper::activeStateChanged(boolean newActive)` as `LifecycleBoundObserver` extends `ObserverWrapper`. The method `activeStateChanged` calls `dispatchingValue()` which in turn calls `LiveData::considerNotify(ObserverWrapper observer)` with the observer wrapper as parameter. This finally calls `onChanged()` upon the observer.

All this happens under certain conditions. I admit that I didn't investigated all conditions within the chain of methods. There are two changes of state, but `onChanged()` is only triggered once, because the conditions check for things like this.

The bottomline here is, that there is a chain of methods, that is triggered upon changes of the lifecycle. This is responsible for the first call.

### Bottomline

I think nothing goes wrong with your code. It's just fine, that the observer is called upon creation. So it can fill itself with the initial data of the view model. That's what an observer should do, even if the database part of the view model is still empty upon the first notification.

### Usage

The first notification basically tells that the view model is ready for to display, despite it still is not loaded with data from underlying databases. The second notification tells, that this data is ready.

When you think of slow db connections, this is a reasonable approach. You may want to retrieve and display other data from the view model triggered by the notification, that does not come from the database.

Android has a guideline how to deal with slow database loading. They suggest to use placeholders. In this example the gap is that short, that there is no reason to go to such an extend.

### Appendix

Both Fragments use there own `ComputableLiveData` objects, that's why the second object is not preloaded from the first fragment.

Also think of the case of rotation. The data of the view model does not change. It does not trigger a notification. The state changes of the lifecycle alone trigger the notification of the new new view.

Comment: `It's just fine, that the observer is called upon creation. So it can fill itself with the initial data of the view model. That's what an observer should do` Imo, if I'm getting subscribed to a data source, I should get the latest state of it. Your statement tells, that it's ok to get some junk (something that actually not corresponds to reality), just ignore that junk. I think that should be considered as a malfunction.

Comment: You ask if the call to  first notification of `onChanged()` delivers an empty list. 

This may in fact be the case, if Rooms is not loaded yet. Then the view model is still empty upon the initial notification and you display an empty list. I would not call that junk. It's just the way it's implemented.

Once Room did it's work, it triggers it's notification and the list is updated. If you watch the Demo, the update follows that fast, that you don't even see the notification of an  empty list.

Comment: The concept behind LiveData obviously is, that you are notified upon two occasions, upon the change of data and upon the change of state of lifecycle.

Comment: I need to add, that displaying placeholders or empty lists for unloaded data is not a bug. That is the official guideline of Android. They want to avoid spinners upon slow connections, which only get into the way.

Comment: `This may in fact be the case, if Rooms is not loaded yet` Certainly, Room is loaded, because it fetches the data to `HomeFragment`. `I would not call that junk. It's just the way it's implemented` The purpose of `LiveData` is to get the actual/fresh/live data, not a stale data, isn't it?

Comment: LiveData has no inbuilt intelligence to know that. It is passive and waits until it is set from side Room. That's the moment the second notification is triggered. It works the way it was designed. If you want something different, then build your own library. The architects have good reasons to choose this approach.

Comment: Honestly? I think it's possible to override the built-in behavior using a MediatorLiveDtaa. I wonder if I'll get the 500 reputation if I write it, lol.

Comment: Lol. The grace period ends in 7 hours. But frankly, I think it is well done as it is. There is nothing wrong for me, getting an early notification, while the DB is still loading. It's easy to check if it's still empty.

Comment: There may be the case, that you want to determine if the emptiness comes from the DB itself. I fear that's a tricky one, as `LiveData::postValue()` does not track the origin of the call. Just taking the order in a MediatorLiveDate is not reliable enough. On the other hand, the notifications be state changes, don't involve `LiveData::postValue()` at all. It could be a suitable criteria.

Answer (score 11):

I snatched Vasiliy's fork of your fork of the fork and did some actual debugging to see what happens.

> Might be related to the way ComputableLiveData offloads onActive() computation to Executor.

Close. The way Room's `LiveData<List<T>>` expose works is that it creates a `ComputableLiveData`, which keeps track of whether your data set has been invalidated underneath in Room.

```
trashedNotesLiveData = NoteplusRoomDatabase.instance().noteDao().getTrashedNotes();
```

So when the `note` table is written to, then the InvalidationTracker bound to the LiveData will call `invalidate()` when a write happens.

```
  @Override
  public LiveData<List<Note>> getNotes() {
    final String _sql = "SELECT * FROM note where trashed = 0";
    final RoomSQLiteQuery _statement = RoomSQLiteQuery.acquire(_sql, 0);
    return new ComputableLiveData<List<Note>>() {
      private Observer _observer;

      @Override
      protected List<Note> compute() {
        if (_observer == null) {
          _observer = new Observer("note") {
            @Override
            public void onInvalidated(@NonNull Set<String> tables) {
              invalidate();
            }
          };
          __db.getInvalidationTracker().addWeakObserver(_observer);
        }
```

Now what we need to know is that `ComputableLiveData`'s `invalidate()` will *actually* refresh the data set, if the LiveData is *active*.

```
// invalidation check always happens on the main thread
@VisibleForTesting
final Runnable mInvalidationRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @MainThread
    @Override
    public void run() {
        boolean isActive = mLiveData.hasActiveObservers();
        if (mInvalid.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            if (isActive) { // <-- this check here is what's causing you headaches
                mExecutor.execute(mRefreshRunnable);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Where `liveData.hasActiveObservers()` is:

```
public boolean hasActiveObservers() {
    return mActiveCount > 0;
}
```

So `refreshRunnable` actually runs only if there is an active observer (afaik means lifecycle is at least started, and observes the live data).

---

---

This means that when you subscribe in TrashFragment, then what happens is that your LiveData is stored in Activity so it is kept alive even when TrashFragment is gone, and retains previous value.

However, when you open TrashFragment, then TrashFragment subscribes, LiveData becomes active, ComputableLiveData checks for invalidation (which is true as it was never re-computed because the live data was not active), computes it asynchronously on background thread, and when it is complete, the value is posted.

So you get two callbacks because:

1.) first "onChanged" call is the previously retained value of the LiveData kept alive in the Activity's ViewModel

2.) second "onChanged" call is the newly evaluated result set from your database, where the computation was triggered by that the live data from Room became active.

---

So technically this is by design. If you want to ensure you only get the "newest and greatest" value, then you should use a fragment-scoped ViewModel.

You might also want to start observing in `onCreateView()`, and use `viewLifecycle` for the lifecycle of your LiveData (this is a new addition so that you don't need to remove observers in `onDestroyView()`.

If it is important that the Fragment sees the latest value even when the Fragment  is NOT active and NOT observing it, then as the ViewModel is Activity-scoped, you might want to register an observer in the Activity as well to ensure that there is an active observer on your LiveData.

Comment: I don't think that SO is the place to have this discussion, but neither is the official issue tracker. So, I'll write here. I think you jumped to conclusions way too quickly. 

1) The fact that something is `by design` doesn't mean that it's not a bug 

2) It already observes in `onCreateView` (not that it matters) 

3) `viewLifecycle` has nothing to do with it 

4) Your last paragraph is basically a hacky workaround for a bug

5) OP, me and @CommonsWare suspect that it's a bug so I opened the ticket for googlers to check it. 

- In this specific case, your input was premature IMHO

Comment: no, `viewLifecycle` really has nothing to do with it. It's all just that Room's LiveData is re-evaluated only if there is at least one active observer. "If a tree falls in the forest and no one's there to hear it, does it make a sound?" in case of ComputableLiveData, apparently not. You typically want to show the data in a RecyclerView + ListAdapter, so it'd handle the changes accordingly using `submitList`.

Comment: That's exactly what both OP and me reported as a bug.

Comment: It's not a bug though, this is how on back navigation, you get insert animations from the list differ, even if the view was detached. I *think*. After thinking about it 10 seconds, I think *now* I'm jumping to conclusions. But it is a possibility.

Comment: There is no point in us arguing whether it's bug or not. I don't see how spurious notification with a wrong state can be anything but a serious bug, but let's let googlers check this thoroughly and the community to react.

Comment: Don't forget another strange behavior based on the observation - "that subscription to LiveData in MainFragment changed the behavior in TrashFragment."

Comment: Yes it did. Having an active observer (MainFragment) allowed ComputableLiveData to trigger refresh of dataset from underlying database.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I have a similar case with the two callbacks here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58790802/room-database-getting-select-max-twice-after-creating-new-recyclerview-item/58858407#58858407.  Any thoughts on how to ignore or bypass the first callback's stored value?

Comment: @AJW stop showing toasts in `roomLiveData.observe` I guess.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Ok so that will stop the double triggering.  But where else could I show the Toast that achieves the objective of notifying the user when new CardView data is saved to the database?

Comment: ^ create an extra LiveData, backed by a MutableLiveData, for the purpose of tracking the status of the operation. Set its value to "done" (however you want to represent that state), then set its status to "irrelevant" (however you want to represent that state, I typically use null and observers simply ignore null), then when subscribing an observer the initial value will be "irrelevant".

Comment: "did some actual debugging" right, because others do slack debugging but you

Comment: This was 100% the issue I was facing and it was causing the data I was saving from this to conflict with the onResume data reloaded in from the activity. In short, this `feature` caused a race condition and I had to ignore saving the result from this callback and instead just let it run twice. It sets the UI twice, but it sounds like it is just `the way it is` for now.

Answer (score 9):

My answer is not a solution to this question description but rather to question title. Just title.

**If your observer for a LiveData<*> is getting called multiple times then it means you are calling livedata.observe(...) multiple times.** This happened to me as I was doing livedata.observe(...) in a method and was calling this method whenever user does some action thus observing liveData again. To solve this I moved livedata.observe(...) to onCreate() lifecycle method.

**What was the scenario?**
The App has a color swatch. When user selects a color I had to make API call to fetch Product Images for that color. So was making API call and was observing livedata in `onColorChanged()` . When user selects a new color, `onColorChanged()` would be called again thus observing for livedata changes again.

Edit: The other issue could be passing ***this*** instead of ***viewLifecycleOwner*** while registering LiveData Observer as pointed out in another answer below. Always use ***viewLifecycleOwner*** when observing LiveData in Fragments.

Comment: +1 for the explaination. Any reference to why: " Always use viewLifecycleOwner when observing LiveData in Fragments." ?

Answer (score 8):

I used [SingleLiveEvent](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/SingleLiveEvent.java) and works. When fragment/activity is resumed or recreated SingleLiveEvent not throw the event, only when explicitly changes

Answer (score 8):

**Never put an observer inside loops/any place where it gets registered twice**. Observers should be put inside onViewCreated / onCreate / any place that gets called only once. OBSERVE ONLY ONCE !

Here is an example of the wrong way :

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
//THIS IS WRONG, DONT PUT IT INSIDE A LOOP / FUNCTION CALL
    yourviewModel.getYourLiveData().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Boolean sBoolean) {
                 //SOME CODE 
            }
 );
}
```

IT IS WRONG TO PUT IT UNDER SOME FUNCTION THAT GETS CALLED MORE THAN ONCE, like:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
observeMyViewModel();
observeMyViewModel();//THIS IS WRONG, CALLING IT MORE THAN ONCE
}

private void observeMyViewModel(){
  yourviewModel.getYourLiveData().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Boolean sBoolean) {
                 //SOME CODE 
            }
 );
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This is what happens under the hood:

```
ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity())
```

As you are using **getActivity()** this retains your NoteViewModel while the scope of MainActivity is alive so is your trashedNotesLiveData.

When you first open your TrashFragment room queries the db and your trashedNotesLiveData is populated with the trashed value (At the first opening there is only one onChange() call). So this value is cached in trashedNotesLiveData.

Then you come to the main fragment add a few trashed notes and go to the TrashFragment again. This time you are first served with the cached value in
trashedNotesLiveData while room makes async query. When query finishes you are
brought the latest value. This is why you get two onChange() calls.

So the solution is you need to clean the trashedNotesLiveData before opening
TrashFragment. This can either be done in your getTrashedNotesLiveData() method.

```
public LiveData<List<Note>> getTrashedNotesLiveData() {
    return NoteplusRoomDatabase.instance().noteDao().getTrashedNotes();
}
```

Or you can use something like this [SingleLiveEvent](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/SingleLiveEvent.java)

Or you can use a MediatorLiveData which intercepts the Room generated one and returns only distinct values.

```
final MediatorLiveData<T> distinctLiveData = new MediatorLiveData<>();
    distinctLiveData.addSource(liveData, new Observer<T>() {
        private boolean initialized = false;
        private T lastObject = null;

        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable T t) {
            if (!initialized) {
                initialized = true;
                lastObject = t;
                distinctLiveData.postValue(lastObject);
            } else if (t != null && !t.equals(lastObject)) {
                lastObject = t;
                distinctLiveData.postValue(lastObject);
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: SingleLiveEvent did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a solution to avoid the multiple triggers on popUp the back stack from destination fragment to the original fragment

> My solution is to observe the LiveData at onCreate() of the Fragment lifecycle **with lifecycle owner as Activity** and remove the observer at
>   onDestroy() of the Fragment lifecycle

Comment: Yeah scoping out live data to activity helped me to resolve this automatic trigger

Comment: @Muhammed Riyas, sorry for necroposting sir, but why does changing owner to Activity prevent multiple triggers?

Answer (score 2):

I found out specifically why it's acting the way it is.  The observed behavior was onChanged() in the trash fragment is called once the first time you activate the fragment after trashing a note (on fresh app start) and gets called twice when fragment get activated thereafter after a note is trashed.

The double calls happen because:

Call #1: The fragment is transitioning between STOPPED and STARTED in its lifecyle and this causes a notification to be set to the LiveData object (it's a  lifecycle observer after all!).  The LiveData code calls the the onChanged() handler because it thinks the observer's version of the data needs to be updated (more on this later).  Note: the actual update to the data could still be pending at this point causing the onChange() to get called with stale data.

Call #2: Ensues as a result of the query setting the LiveData (normal path).  Again the LiveData object thinks the observer's version of the data is stale.

Now why does onChanged() only get called **once** the very first time the view is activated after app startup?  It's because the first time the LiveData version checking code executes as a result of the STOPPED->STARTED transition the live data has never been set to anything and thus LiveData skips informing the observer.  Subsequent calls through this code path (see considerNotify() in LiveData.java) execute after the data has been set at least once.

LiveData determines if the observer has stale data by keeping a version number that indicates how many times the data has been set. It also records the version number last sent to the client.  When new data is set LiveData can compare these versions to determine if an onChange() call is warranted.

Here's the version #s during the calls to the LiveData version checking code for the 4 calls:

```
   Ver. Last Seen  Ver. of the     OnChanged()
   by Observer     LiveData        Called?
  --------------   --------------- -----------
1  -1 (never set)  -1 (never set)  N
2  -1              0               Y
3  -1              0               Y
4   0              1               Y
```

If you're wondering why version last seen by the observer in call 3 is -1 even though onChanged() was called the 2nd time around it's because the observer in calls 1/2 is a different observer than the one in calls 3/4 (the observer is in the fragment which was destroyed when the user went back to the main fragment).

An easy way to avoid confusion regarding the spurious calls that happen as a result of lifecycle transitions is to keep a flag in the fragment intialized to false that indicates if the fragment has been fully resumed.  Set that flag to true in the onResume() handler then check to see if that flag is true in your onChanged() handler.  That way you can be sure you're responding to events that happened becuase data was truly set.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this issue is still active.

But the main perpetrator was a bug inside the fragment Lifecycle owner for fragments which was not cleared when the view was destroyed.

Previously you would have to implement your own lyfecycle owner that would move the state to `destroyed` when `onDestroyView` would be called.

This should no longer be the case if you target and compile with at least API 28

Answer (score 0):

I observed most of the time in Fragment, if we are initialing ViewModel globally, which leads to create observer multiple time we call onViewCreated(),
So, better do not initialize globally but on onViewCreated() only, so, every time, ViewModel gives you new instance. so, observer also.

Answer (score -1):

Here's how to fix this in kotlin:

In room DAO, use `Flow<List<T>>` instead of `LiveData<List<T>>`.

So, in the OP's example we can use:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM note where trashed = 1")
fun getTrashedNotes(): Flow<List<Note>>
```

instead of

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM note where trashed = 1")
fun getTrashedNotes(): LiveData<List<Note>>
```

Then in viewModel, we can use `val list = dao.getTrashedNotes().asLiveData()`.

So OP's viewModel will be:

```
val trashedNotesLiveData = NoteplusRoomDatabase.instance().noteDao().getTrashedNotes().asLiveData()
```

And rest of the flows after viewModel remains the same.

Reason why this works:

Flow, unlike liveData, is not lifecycle aware. So, even if the fragment is not created, flow's value will be up-to date.

Comment: Question is asked for livedata. You can not change livedata to flow for only one case in app.

Answer (score -3):

The solution I had was simply to start observing data when I need it and remove the observer as soon as it has retrieved the data. You won't get double triggering this way.

Comment: I have a similar case with the two callbacks here: stackoverflow.com/questions/58790802/…. Any thoughts on how to ignore or bypass the first callback's stored value?