# Android LiveData observe is called multiple times

Tags: android, kotlin, android-lifecycle, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I have a `BaseActivity` which has a `MutableLiveData` field as below

```
val refInfoLiveData: MutableLiveData<RefInfo?> by lazy { MutableLiveData<RefInfo?>() }
```

A network call is made to populate this `MutableLiveData` field when `onStart` method of the `BaseActivity` is called.

I also have a couple of `Fragment`s which are parts of an `Activity` that inherits the `BaseActivity`.

In one if these fragments I am making another call in `onResume` method of the fragment as below

```
    (activity as BaseActivity).refInfoLiveData.observe(this, Observer {
        it?.let { refInfo ->
            adapter?.setRefInfo(refInfo)
        }
    })
```

When the fragment is created for the first time `observe` only called once but the fragment goes to background then comes back it is called multiple times and that is causing issues.

What could be the reason of this problem and how can I solve it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: check this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50236778/why-livedata-observer-is-being-triggered-twice-for-a-newly-attached-observer

Comment: @ZachBvy that is a different problem, only applicable to query results obtained from Room.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you are supposed to be using `observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { ...` inside `onViewCreated`.

```
import androidx.lifecycle.observe

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    (activity as BaseActivity).refInfoLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { refInfo ->
        refInfo?.let { adapter.setRefInfo(it) }
    }
}
```

Currently you'll have an infinite number of subscribers if you put the app in background then bring it foreground an infinite number of times.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.javatpoint.com/android-life-cycle-of-activity

Maybe you could try to use another lifecyclehook, because `onResume()` is called most often of the entry hooks.

Try it in the `onCreate()`.

Comment: Moving it to onActivityCreated would solve that problem but in my case it creates different problems so I kind of need to keep it in onResume

Comment: Don't use `onActivityCreated`, there is no reason to use it in any scenarios that I know of 

Comment: @Tartar, if you want to keep it in `onResume`, you need to implement your own `LifeCycleOwner` instead of using the default `viewLifecycleOwner`.

Comment: @d4ku3, please include some relevant content from the linked page, in case the link gets broken. It would also be helpful to tell readers what they will find by following the link.

Comment: @Preacher sure, maybe you could tell me how to include pics ^^, wanted to show the lifecycle diagram

Comment: @d4ku3 I don't know, off hand. I'd have to go figure it out. But in lieu, you may be able to present the diagram as a sequence of steps, having the last step being "repeat" to show the cyclic nature.