# Room database: getting SELECT MAX() twice after creating new RecyclerView item

Tags: android, android-room, android-viewmodel

I have a RecyclerView list of CardView items that is working properly.  Upon creation of a new CardView that is inserted into the database, I would like to fire a Toast that informs the user that the CardView was successfully added and show the CardView number.  The CardView number is the Id of the CardView item inserted into the database.  The data is saved to the database when the user clicks on a Save button that fires onClickSave().

I set up an @Query in the Dao to get the MAX(cardId):

```
Dao
...
@Query("SELECT MAX(cardId) FROM cards")
LiveData<Integer> getMax();

@Insert
void insertCard(Card card);
```

Problem is that two Toasts are firing.  The first Toast is returning the previously created CardView number **and** then the second Toast is firing and it shows the latest CardView number that was just added.  For example, the Toast will show CardView number 33 and then a second Toast fires that shows the expected CardView number 34 that was just created (I confirm that CardViews 33 and 34 are both in the database and the two highest items, using DB Browser for SQLite software).

```
AddorUpdateCardActivity
...
private int newMax = -1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(cardViewModel.class);        
}

public void onClickSave(View v) {

    // set card data
    // then insert data in database
    mViewModel.insertCard(card1);     

    mViewModel.getMax().observe(this, value -> { newMax = value; Toast.makeText(AddorUpdateCardActivity.this, "card #" + newMax + " was saved to the list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();});
}

ViewModel
...

public cardViewModel(Application application) {
    super(application);
    repository = new cardRepository(application);
    getMax = repository.getMax();
}

public LiveData<Integer> getMax() {
    return getMax;
}

public void insertCard(Card card) {
    repository.insertCard(card);
}

cardRepository

private CardDao cardDao;
private LiveData<Integer> getMax;


public cardRepository(Application application) {
    RoomDatabase db = RoomDatabase.getDatabase(application);
    cardDao = db.cardDao();
}

public LiveData<Integer> getMax() {
    return cardDao.getMax;  
}

public void insertCard(Quickcard newcard) {
    AsyncTask.execute(() -> cardDao.insertCard(newcard));

}
```

What am I missing here?  If the card is inserted properly into the database then why wouldn't the ViewModel observer just return this new CardView number rather than two Toasts?

For reference, I show the previous code I used prior to Room and ViewModel that used a cursor to get the latest and highest inserted Id:

```
public class SQLiteDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    ...
    public int getLastInsertId() {

    int index = 0;
    SQLiteDatabase sdb = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = sdb.query(
            "sqlite_sequence",
            new String[]{"seq"},
            "name = ?",
            new String[]{TABLE_NAME},
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null
    );

    sdb.beginTransaction();
    try {
        if (cursor !=null) { 
            if (cursor.moveToLast()) {                    
                index = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("seq"));
            }
        }
    ...
    }         
    return index;
}
```

Comment: There is not ` mViewModel.insertCard(card1);  ` method in `ViewModel`. Share that part of code.

Comment: @GensaGames  Will do, by 6pm ET USA.

Comment: @GensaGames ViewModel's insertCard() has been upated.  And the same for the Repository and the Dao.

Comment: Can you move the Toast inside ```mViewModel.getMax().observe()```? Your Toast might the firing before the data was saved and ```newMax``` value is update. @AJW

Comment: @Prokash Sarkar I understand your point but I am not sure how to move the Toast inside.  Can you provide an example?

Comment: @AJW Like this? ```mViewModel.getMax().observe(this, value -> {
            newMax = value;
            Toast.makeText(AddorUpdateCardActivity.this, "card #" + newMax + " was saved to the list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        });``` This makes sure the Toast will be fired when a data change occured inside Room.

Comment: @Prokash Sarkar  Ah, I see.  This way newMax is updated and the Toast is fired after, yes?

Comment: @AJW Exactly! Let me know if that works.

Comment: @Prokash Sarkar  Ok so I moved the "mViewModel.getMax().observe..." code out of onCreate() and put it just below "mViewModel.insertCard(card1)".  The Toast fired but it fired twice.  First it fired and said the previous card # was just saved.  Then it fired again and said the last card # was just saved.  So making progress because the second Toast correctly fired and showed the correct card # saved for the last card that was just inserted into the database.  But the first Toast should not be firing because that CardView was previously saved.

Comment: @Prokash Sarkar I am also using getMax() in another Activity to observe the MAX from the database.  Perhaps there is a conflict with the two Observers so that is why it is firing twice.  I will re-name getMax() in the AddorUpdateCardActivity to see if that solves the problem.  Let me know if you have any other ideas on how to fix.

Comment: @AJW You used different Dao *instance* for insert and observe. They needs to be same across all operations.

Comment: So because there are two Dao instances the Toast is firing twice?

Comment: @Prokash Sarkar How do I make the Dao instance the same?  Change the Dao instance in the repository for observe to match the Dao instance in the Async Task for insert?

Comment: @AJW I've posted my answer. Let me know if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view model operations you call within `onClickSave` are asynchronous:

```
public void onClickSave(View v) {
    mViewModel.insertCard(card1);
    mViewModel.getMax().observe(this, value -> { newMax = value; makeText(AddorUpdateCardActivity.this, "TEXT", .LENGTH_LONG).show();});
}
```

The implementation of `LiveData` records the data version as well as the last version seen by the observer.

Therefore `insertCard` starts to operate on a worker thread while you start observing `getMax` from the main thread with a newly created observer. Thus you'll receive the current value as well as the new value after the database was updated.

Instead you could observe it only once in `onCreate()` and wait for the updates triggered by the database:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(cardViewModel.class);
    mViewModel.getMax().observe(this, value -> { newMax = value; makeText(AddorUpdateCardActivity.this, "TEXT", .LENGTH_LONG).show();});
}

public void onClickSave(View v) {
    mViewModel.insertCard(card1);
}
```

Comment: Ah, ok.  So how do I limit the Toast to only get triggered by the insert method (when a CardView is added to the database) so that it does not fire when other CRUD operations occur like a delete or update method?

Comment: I captured the existing MAX from the database and then compared it to the MAX after the insertCard() to determine that a new card was added.  Answer accepted, upvoted and bounty awarded.  Cheers to you.

Comment: Follow-up question:  if I place the getMax() observer in the onCreate(), how can I determine that the update has been triggered by the database?  So I can make sure I obtain the latest version not the data version.

Comment: I don't think `getMax` should be used to determine the correctness of `insertCard`. You should trust _Room_ to always return the correct state from the database. You should use the result of the data base insertion call to verify if the insertion was successful.

Comment: Ok, so how do I make sure that the code to verify the insertion was successful runs just after the insertion?  A button-click on the "Save" button runs the insertCard code.  Just after the insert, I am trying to set up PendingIntents on the card to later fire alarms for Notifications.  I am trying to get data from the newly inserted card (e.g., card.getId()) to set up the PendingIntents but I'm not sure how to get that data within the same code block of "onClickSave".  I'd appreciate any insights or ideas on how to correct.

Comment: I'd suggest to ask another question. This is too much information to answer with just a little comment. Feel free to leave a link to the new question here.

Answer (score 1):

The Room `Insert` operation inside `AsyncTask` takes a while before the `maxCount` variable is updated. Since you are showing the `Toast` inside a button click, the message is displayed right away without receiving the updated value from `LiveData`.

Move the `Toast` message inside the `obverve()` method so that it gets triggered only after a `LiveData` change.

```
mViewModel.getMax().observe(this, value -> {
        newMax = value;
        Toast.makeText(AddorUpdateCardActivity.this, "card #" + newMax + " was saved to the list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    });
```

At this point, the code should be working but you'll get multiple `LiveData` events for a single `Insert`. This is happening because you have used 2 separate instances of **Dao** for `Insert` and `Query` operation.

```
public cardRepository(Application application) {
    RoomDatabase db = RoomDatabase.getDatabase(application);
    cardDao = db.cardDao(); // <---------- Instance #1
    getMax = cardDao.getMax();
}

public LiveData<Integer> getMax() {
    return getMax;  
}

 public void insertCard(Card newcard) {
    new InsertAsyncTask(quickcardDao).execute(newcard);
}

private static class InsertAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Card, Void, Integer> {

    private CardDao asyncTaskDao;

    InsertAsyncTask(CardDao dao) {
        asyncTaskDao = dao; // <---------- Instance #2
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(final Card... params) {

        asyncTaskDao.insertCard(params[0]);
        return null;
    }
}
```

To resolve it use the same **Dao** instance everywhere:

```
public cardRepository(Application application) {
        RoomDatabase db = RoomDatabase.getDatabase(application);
        cardDao = db.cardDao();
    }

    public LiveData<Integer> getMax() {
        return cardDao.getMax();  
    }

     public void insertCard(Card newcard) {
        AsyncTask.execute(() -> cardDao.insertCard(newcard));
    }
```

Comment: Ah, ok will give your fix a try.  I should have the same Dao instance for all CRUD operations, correct?  So deleteCard() and updateCard() should also be using "cardDao..." not their own unique Dao instance?

Comment: The Toast fired but it fired twice again, even after making one Dao instance for insert() and getMax().  See the revised code above based on your answer.  First the Toast fired and said the previous card # was saved. Then it fired again and said the last card # was saved. So the second Toast correctly fired and showed the correct card # saved for the last card that was just inserted into the database. But the first Toast should not be firing because that CardView was previously saved.  Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Because of using AsyncTask to insert card to database, that function take some time to complete and you show your toast, instantly! Change your activity to this:

```
AddorUpdateCardActivity
...
private int newMax = -1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(cardViewModel.class);

    mViewModel.getMax().observe(this, integer2 -> {
        newMax = integer2;
        Toast.makeText(AddorUpdateCardActivity.this, "card #" + newMax + " was saved to the list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        hideProgressBar();
    });
}

public void onClickSave(View v) {

    //set card data
    // then insert data in database
    mViewModel.insertCard(card1);

    showProgressBar();
}
```

Comment: I would like the Toast to be fired after the user click inserts the new CardView data into the database.  So wouldn't I have to move the observer code of mViewModel.getMax()... out of onCreate() and put it right after mViewModel.insertCard() in the onClickSave()?  If not, how is the Toast triggered if it sits in onCreate()?

Comment: In addition, the app crashes when the List is empty and I try to add the first card using AddorUpdateCardActivity.  The Logcat says the integer is null object reference.