# View Model variable in being observed more than once

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvvm, viewmodel, android-toast

I'm having a peculiar issue. In my code, I observe a `MutableLiveData` of type `String` in view Model and display the context as a toast. When I run it in the **AVD**, the toast is being displayed more than once i.e the `MutableLiveData`  is being observed more than once. But, when I run the same code in my Mobile, toast is displayed only once (works as expected).

Code (Fragment):

```
if(!viewModel.messageDisplayed) {
                viewModel.MessageStatus.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
                    it.toast(context)
                    viewModel.messageDisplayed = true // I'm using this variable to avoid displaying the toast multiple 
                                                     //times but it does not work in the emulator 
                })
            }
```

Code (ViewModel):

```
val MessageStatus = MutableLiveData<String>()

fun fireStoreOperations(){
    //fireStore Operations
        .addOnSuccessListener{
         messageDisplayed= False
         MessageStatus.value = "Message to be displayed"
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the observer in the `onActivityCreated` of your fragment. So it would look something like

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    viewModel.MessageStatus.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
                it.toast(context)
                viewModel.messageDisplayed = true 
            })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check that you are calling this method once. 
if your observer for a LiveData<*> should not be called multiple times.
for more details
[this can help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50385170/8057702)